# What happens if I uninstall my motherboards audio driver?

Tags: audio, drivers, motherboard

I have an MPG Z390M Gaming edge AC motherboard from MSI running windows 10. Recently my front and back audio have both stopped working. In response to this I decided to update my audio driver. This both uninstalled my current driver and installed the newer version. I noticed that once the old driver was uninstalled my front and back audio worked fine, it even removed an annoying distortion effect I had heard previously. Once reinstalled, though, the front and back ports stopped working again.

My question is... **Does anything bad happen as a result of not having any audio drivers?** If the only purpose of them is accessibility to functions then surely the most important function is being able to hear audio surely. Am I damaging hardware or simply hearing worse audio? Is it just that I don't have as much access to control settings as if it were working? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that happens when you don't have audio drivers, is that you don't have audio anymore. Nothing else should happen.

Edit: These instructions are to disable auto reinstallation of the drivers. They are from [Appuals.com](https://appuals.com/how-to-disable-windows-10-from-automatically-installing-realtek-drivers/)

> Press Windows/Start Key + R to open Run
>
> Type appwiz.cpl on the run textbox and hit enter.
>
> From the Programs and Features window, double click on Realtek HD Audio Manager to uninstall the program. This will also uninstall the sound drivers, so we will need to reinstall them.
>
> Go to Device Manager by: pressing Windows/Start Key + R and type devmgmt.msc in the run box and hit enter. Right-click Realtek HD Audio Device from (the sounds video and game controller expansion) and choose “Update Driver’.
>
> A Dialogue will appear with options to automatically search for the driver online, search on disk or select from a list. Choose to select from a list. A list will appear containing the Realtek driver and the Microsoft generic driver. Select the Microsoft driver (High Definition Audio Device) and OK. You will get a warning about compatibility but ignore it.
>
> Go to this local disk C: path: C:\Program Files\Realtek\Audio\HDA
>
> Right click anywhere that is blank and choose properties.
>
> Go the security tab and click on Edit
>
> Select “SYSTEM” by clicking on it on the Group or user names options.
>
> In the Permissions for SYSTEM, check the denycheckbox in the full control option.
>
> Press OK twice to accept these changes
>
> Restart your computer

Comment: Just for future reference we have a help page on [how to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing) that includes help on preferred formatting and referencing.

Comment: @Mokubai OK thank you